# Linktrack variables and events set globally in Omniture, causing the event to fire on other actions

Tags: analytics, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to fire some tracking info on link clicks and I've been trying out functions I put together from different places I found online.

After some testing I ended up with two functions that fired what I wanted. However, these seem to be writing to global object, since after the function is called the event keeps firing in other places. I got around this by adding the last line, but this seems like a band-aid that might be covering up a potentially bigger issue. What am I doing wrong in the first place, and what should I be doing to avoid this? I couldn't get the events to fire without writing to the s.events object

```
function f1(){
    s.linkTrackVars= s.linkTrackVars+',eVar45,events';
    s.eVar45='Chat button exposed';
    s.linkTrackEvents = s.events = 'event11'; // hmmm
    s.tl(this, 'o', 'blah');
    s.linkTrackVars = s.linkTrackEvents = s.events = ""; // Added this to empty the global objects
    }

function f2(){
        s.linkTrackVars= s.linkTrackVars+',eVar46,prop45,events';
        s.eVar46='Clicked chat button';
        s.prop45='Clicked chat button';
        s.linkTrackEvents = s.events = 'event31'; // hmmm
        s.tl(this, 'o', 'blah');
        s.linkTrackVars = s.linkTrackEvents =  s.events = ""; // Added this to empty the global objects
        }
```

I'm guessing the issue is the line marked "hmm" but that was the only way I could get the event to fire, if I remove either s.linkTrackEvents or s.events it doesn't fire the event. Either way it seems I have to set all variables to empty strings to avoid the values being used by other actions. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, when you want to send variables to Adobe Analytics via an `s.tl()` call, yes, they must be "registered" with `linkTrackEvents` and `linkTrackVars`.

However, you can [pass the variables in an object as the 4th argument](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/function_tl.html) to use the values for that call but not permanently set them. You still need to "register" the vars with `linkTrackEvents` and `linkTrackVars` so that needs to go in the payload, too.

**Example**

```
function f1() {
  var payload={
    'linkTrackEvents':'event1',
    'linkTrackVars':'events,eVar1',
    'events':'event1',
    'eVar1':'bar'
  }
  s.tl(true,'o','some action',payload)
}

/* 
  first we have the var set, maybe as default values 
  in some config initially loaded on page
*/
s.linkTrackEvents='None';
s.linkTrackVars='None';
s.events='';
s.eVar1='foo';

// example to see current values above
console.log(s); 

/* 
  then call the function. You will see in the 
  request that event1 is set and eVar1 is 'bar'
*/
f1();

/* 
  now another console log to see the values, 
  you will see it's the original values
*/
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Hey any way I can get in touch with you directly? kjackson@phelpsagency.com